# Django production (using gunicorn) - internal server error (no request) until 10-20 requests have been made

Tags: django

I have a production system that has been running for 2+ years now, regularly (daily/weekly) updates. Around 2 months ago, a strange behaviour occurs every time I restart Gunicorn, for the first 10-20 requests made to the web server, I get an internal server error. The errors (when the system is switched to debug=True) all relate the the request being None.

The login (allauth) page works a treat, but once I have entered my account details (or any other) - I get internal server error on the following URL. If I reload, it loads AOK. If I browse the site, I get a mixture (semi random) of pages that either load or internal server error. After around 10-20 page load attempts - every thing starts working 100% AOK. No issues.

I can then log in as any account, every page works. The above issues on restarting the web server also occurs with any other account login.

Its as if there is something that is failing in the middleware or some sort of internal time out before the request details can be stored. But, the database server is fully up and running, no load issues at all.

Any thoughts on the issue or how I could go about fixing this. Before this I could update the production servers without any down time, not this is causing around 4-5 minutes of downtime any time I want to update code.

Some additional info - no issue when running locally runserver etc...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Including the full error you see with debug logging enabled will help.

Comment: It will be hard for anyone to help without seeing any code or traceback. Can you review commits over the past two months to try and diagnose the issue? Presumably your tests didn't pick up any issues. A service like sentry could be helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your time and apologies for not including more info on the initial post.

Ended up that I was using --preload on our Gunicorn config. This has worked a treat for almost 3 years in production but seems that this was causing every 'worker' to need at least 2 requests to it, before it would start processing them. Weird eh?

I needed to wait until this weekend as we had some planned down time and I could isolate Production, try it with Debug etc.... None of this helped! but I started setting the number of workers from 1 to 13 and the number of requests it took to get a proper reply (rather than Internal Server error) was two times the number of workers.

So - then I just happened to try removing the --preload option and everything worked exactly as it has before about 3 months ago.

Memory increase is not an issue - so I will move forwards with this.

The stack trace whilst in debug I got was:

OperationalError at /company/person_overview/

```
SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://www.mowida.com/company/person_overview/
Django Version: 3.2.15
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected
Exception Location: /home/timothy/.pyenv/versions/3.9.13/envs/mwp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py, line 84, in _execute
Python Executable:  /home/timothy/.pyenv/versions/3.9.13/envs/mwp/bin/python3.9
Python Version: 3.9.13
Python Path:    
['/home/timothy/.virtualenvs/mwp/lib/python3.9/site-packages',
 '/mwp/mwp',
 '/home/timothy/.pyenv/versions/3.9.13/envs/mwp/bin',
 '/home/timothy/.pyenv/versions/3.9.13/lib/python39.zip',
 '/home/timothy/.pyenv/versions/3.9.13/lib/python3.9',
 '/home/timothy/.pyenv/versions/3.9.13/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
 '/home/timothy/.pyenv/versions/3.9.13/envs/mwp/lib/python3.9/site-packages',
 '/mwp/mwp/mwp']
Server time:    Sat, 13 Aug 2022 22:52:37 +0200

Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
/home/timothy/.pyenv/versions/3.9.13/envs/mwp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py, line 84, in _execute
                return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) …
▶ Local vars
The above exception (SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected ) was the direct cause of the following exception:
/home/timothy/.pyenv/versions/3.9.13/envs/mwp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py, line 47, in inner
                response = get_response(request) …
▶ Local vars
/home/timothy/.pyenv/versions/3.9.13/envs/mwp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py, line 204, in _get_response
                response = response.render()
```

I have included this to help anyone else who might get the same issue.

One last thought is why this started happening around 3 months ago?  Gunicorn has not updated, our config has not been updated/changed.

Thanks again for thoughts.